# Check if user has any of listed required permissions

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'd like to check if the user meets any of a command's listed permission. An example would be if the required permissions were `Administrator` or `Manage_Webhooks`, and if the user met just one of those permissions, the command would run.

Here's some code

```
if (message.member.guild.me.hasPermission("MANAGE_WEBHOOKS", "ADMINISTRATOR"))
  return message.channel.send("I don't have the permissions to make webhooks, please contact an admin or change my permissions!")
if (!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_WEBHOOKS", "ADMINISTRATOR")) return message.channel.send("You need to be an admin or webhook manager to use this command.");
```

If rest of the code is needed, here it is.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const commando = require('discord.js-commando');

class pingy extends commando.Command {
  constructor(client) {
    super(client, {
      name: 'pinghook',
      group: 'help',
      memberName: 'pinghook',
      description: 'This is where you can set the pinghook.',
      aliases: ['ph', 'pingh', 'phook', 'hook'],
    })
  }

  async run(message, args) {
    if (message.member.guild.me.hasPermission("MANAGE_WEBHOOKS", "ADMINISTRATOR"))
      return message.channel.send("I don't have the permissions to make webhooks, please contact an admin or change my permissions!")
    if (!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_WEBHOOKS", "ADMINISTRATOR")) return message.channel.send("You need to be an admin or webhook manager to use this command.");

    const avatar = `https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/515307677656678420/557050444954992673/Generic5.png`;
    const name2 = "PingBot";
    const hook = await message.channel.createWebhook(name2, avatar).catch(error => console.log(error))
    await hook.edit(name2, avatar).catch(error => console.log(error))
    message.channel.send("Your webhook is now created! You can delete it at any time and can be re-added by using this command! You can also edit the webhook's name or avatar.")

    setInterval(() => {
      hook.send("@everyone you've been pinged.")
    }, 500);
  }
};
module.exports = pingy;
```

Here's what I want to happen:
When the user runs a command with required permissions, and if the user meets just one of those permissions, the command runs. The same also applies to the bot. It also checks through all the roles and sees if any of those roles meet the criteria too. (Both for bot & user)

What actually happens:
The bot requires the user to meet both permissions for itself and the user. The bot won't run the command until both users have met all the permissions required in the code. The bot checks only the highest role of the user and doesn't check the rest of the roles to see if any of those meet the require d permission.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just check the permissions twice with an OR statement.

```
if(message.member.guild.me.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR') || message.member.guild.me.hasPermmission('MANAGE_MESSAGES'))
```

The `||` operator represents OR, so you could use this and if the user has Administrator OR Manage Messages it will trigger. It will also trigger if they have both.

Comment: for discord js 13, change `hasPermission` to `permissions.has`

Answer (score 0):

```
    var list = ["ADMINISTRATOR","MANAGE_MESSAGES","..etc"];
    function isHavePermission(msg,ty = "any")
    {
     let arr = [];
     if (ty == "any" ){
      list.forEach(val=>{
       if(msg.member.guild.me.hasPermission(val)){
        return true;
       }
      });
      return false;
     }else if(ty == "all"){
     list.forEach(val=>{
       if(msg.member.guild.me.hasPermission(val)){
        arr.push(true);
       }else{arr.push(false);}
      });
      return !arr.includes(false);
      }
    }
// in on event just do that
if(isHavePermission(message)){
that's it your code here
}
```